# Recovering SQL Express 2016 RC1 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

This afternoon, I tried to log on to my local SQL Server 2016 RC1 instance and it failed. Looking at the logs I learn that the service won't start because the "Evaluation Period has ended", which was great, I didn't get any warnings about this period ending which has led me into my current predicament.

I had quite a large database on there which I was working on locally while travelling and made a few significant changes to which I'd rather not have to go back and remake.

What options do I have to recover this database into a new 'fully fledged' SQL Express Instance?

I've tried the [activation idea here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/06/22/sql-server-evaluation-period-has-expired-how-to-activate-sql-server/) but it doesn't upgrade the actual database engine, just the other elements. Which is similar to what happens when I try repairing it, just that more elements are repaired.

The actual Primary Database file and log are available, is there anyway I can import these?

Comment: Add a new instance of the *released* version and you should be able to attach them (depending on whether the SQL Server service was shut down gracefully - you may be out of luck). For important databases you should always have a proper and tested backup and recovery strategy in place. This is a risk you take with pre-release software and no backups of your database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to attach your database files using the instructions in the documentation: [How to: Attach a Database File to SQL Server Express](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165673(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I had some issues with permissions as I think the Data folder now is protected in 2016 vs 2005.

I found the SSMS approach [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx) easier to use particularly when running SSMS as an administrator